# Using props as the key property in React inline style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline-styles

In React, [inline styles](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of the style name. How would you use props as the key value?

**E.g.:**

```
const {
    position
} = this.props;

let triangleStyle = {
    borderLeft: '5px solid transparent',
    borderRight: '5px solid transparent',
    `border${position}`: '5px solid red'
};

function Component() {
    return <div style={triangleStyle}></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are computing the key value for the style we can could:

Put all the logic inside the Component, using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
function Component({ position }) {
  const triangleStyle = {
    borderLeft: '5px solid transparent'
    borderRight: '5px solid transparent',
    [`border${position}`]: '5px solid red',
  }

  return <div style={triangleStyle} />
}
```

Alternatively, extract the triangle styles to a function

```
const getTriangleStyle = position => ({
  borderLeft: '5px solid transparent'
  borderRight: '5px solid transparent',
  [`border${position}`]: '5px solid red',
})

function Component({ position }) {
  return <div style={getTriangleStyle(position)} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
const triangleStyleFoo = (position) => ({
    borderLeft: '5px solid transparent',
    borderRight: '5px solid transparent',
    `border${position}`: '5px solid red'
});

function Component() {
    const { position } = this.props;
    const triangleStyle = this.triangleStyleFoo(position);
    return <div style={triangleStyle}></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const {
    position
} = this.props;

let triangleStyle = {
    borderLeft: '5px solid transparent',
    borderRight: '5px solid transparent'
};

triangleStyle[`border${position}`] = '5px solid red'
function Component() {
    return <div style={triangleStyle}></div>;
}
```